# Org-mode troubleshooting navigate heading jump C-c C-J

Tags: org-mode

I've been trying to use org-mode over a year and still get stuck on seemingly simple questions.

When I search/navigate jump and type in text after `C-c C-j` I can RET and `C-g` but cannot `[Up]/[Down]` or `[/]`. Why and how?

What do the square bracket mean in the context help? Is it me? Where best to find help myself on these issues?

Context help from `C-c C-j`:

```
Browse buffer copy, to find location or copy text.  Just type for auto-isearch.
RET=jump to location             C-g=quit and return to previous location
[Up]/[Down]=next/prev headline   TAB=cycle visibility   [/] org-occur
```

Comment: You should learn to use the Emacs Help system: do `C-h ?` and start exploring. In this case, if you do `C-h c C-c C-j` (that is, find the binding of the key `C-c C-j`, i.e. the function that is called), you will find out that `C-c C-j` ends up calling the function `org-goto`. You can then ask for help on that function with `C-h f org-goto` and read its documentation string. And you can also read the Org mode manual inside Emacs: `C-h i org mode` and then search in the manual by using its index with `i org-goto`. Both of these sources of information (the doc string and the manual) should help.

Comment: The up and down arrow keys work as described for me following `C-c C-j` in an Org buffer.